# Cosets of $\mathbb Z \times (\mathbb Z \setminus 3 \mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to find the cosets of
$$G =\mathbb Z \times (\mathbb Z \setminus 3 \mathbb Z)$$
With respect to this subgroup:
$$H = \{0 \} \times (\mathbb Z \setminus 3 \mathbb Z)$$
Where the operation on the latter group is addition modulo $3$. 
According to the definition of a coset, I need to take all elements of my initial group and multiply each of them by every element of $H$, so that I get a new set. The set is the coset I am looking for. 
Therefore, I take an arbitrary element $g \in G$:
$$g = (z, c) \text{ where }z \in \mathbb{Z} \text { and } c \in \{0,1,2\} $$
$$gH = (z,c) \cdot (0, d) \text{ where } d\in \{0,1,2 \} =(z+0,  (c+d)  \% 3) = (z, c)$$
And so, $gH$ = $\mathbb Z \times \{0,1,2\}$ 
Where $\%$ is the modulo operator. 
Is it the correct approach to solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach is the right one.

---

A few comments regarding notation:

- When working with abelian groups, it is customary to denote the group operation with $"+"$ rather than $"\cdot"$.
- It is good notation to distinguish the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ using bars over them, that is, by writing $$\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} = \{ \bar{0}, \bar{1}, \bar{2} \}$$ rather than $$\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} = \{ 0,1,2 \}.$$ This is because in the latter case, it might be possible to confuse the elements with the regular integers.

---

One mistake in your final step (along with another comment on notation):

- The coset $gH$ is (also) a set, so it should be represented as such. I would write the computation you have given in the following manner:
  $$
  \begin{align}
  gH &= (z,\bar{c}) + \{ (0,\bar{d}) : d \in \{0,1,2\} \} \\
  &= \{ (z + 0,\bar{c} + \bar{d}) : d \in \{ 0,1,2 \} \} \\
  &= \{ (z,\overline{c + d}) : d \in \{ 0,1,2 \} \} \\
  &= \{ (z,\bar{d}) : d \in \{ 0,1,2 \} \}.
  \end{align}
  $$
  So, $$gH = \{z\} \times \{ \bar{0}, \bar{1}, \bar{2} \} = \{z\} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}.$$ Note that this answer is different from what you have written! I hope it is clear where there was a mistake in your reasoning.

If anything is unclear in what I've written then feel free to ask in the comments below.

Comment: Why is the final answer not $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \setminus 3 \mathbb  Z$? $z$ can be any integer.

Comment: To compute the coset $gH$, you fix the element $g = (z,c)$ in $G$ and add it to each element of $H$. So, $z$ is fixed when computing $gH$. It is not an arbitrary integer when you are computing the particular coset $gH$.

Comment: The collection of all cosets of $H$ in $G$ can be described by varying $z$ over all the integers. But even in this case, the variation does not change any individual coset $gH$. So, we cannot even say that the collection of all cosets is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$. Instead, what we should say is that the collection of all cosets is of the form $\{ \{z\} \times \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z} : z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Also note that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is in fact the original group $G$. A coset of a (non-trivial) subgroup cannot be the original group itself.